# Jquery methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep seeing codes like this:

```
  $(document.documentElement).keyup( function(event) {
    var slides = $('#slides .pagination li'),
        current = slides.filter('.current');

    switch( event.keyCode ) {
      case 37: // Left arrow
        if ( slides.filter(':first').is( current ) ) {
          slides.filter(':last').find('a').click();
        } else {
          slides.eq( slides.index(current) - 1 ).find('a').click();
        }
        break;
      case 39: // Right arrow
        if ( slides.filter(':last').is( current ) ) {
          slides.filter(':first').find('a').click();
        } else {
          current.find('+ li').filter(':first').find('a').click();
        }
        break;
    }
  });
```

For a line like this: `current = slides.filter('.current');`, `.filter()` is a jquery method, right? Then shouldn't it be `current = $(slides).filter('.current');`.

Does it work the way it is done in the code? Why?

Comment: `$()` is a function which returns a jQuery object. That object now has the jQuery functions on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`slides` is a jQuery object so you don't need to wrap it in `$()` like you do with a DOM object.

So `slides.filter('.current')` works like `$('#slides .pagination li').filter('.current')`. It's important to keep track of whether your objects are jQuery selectors, jQuery objects, and/or DOM objects.

Some people like to name their jQuery objects like `var $slides` as a mental note.

Comment: It's to reduce confusion about what's a "jQuery" variable and what's not that I employ the convention of prefixing jQuery variables with `$`. So, if I had written it, you'd have said `var $slides = $('#slides .pagination li'); current = $slides.filter('.current');`. I think this adds useful clarity, but maybe it's just the rebel Perl hacker in me.

Answer (score 0):

slides is already 'jQuery'ed: notice that it's defined using the `$` sign. so there's no need to wrap it with a `$` again.